# What is the meaning of the version of the index in Solr Core Admin?

Tags: solr

When viewing Solr admin, clicking on "Core Admin", selecting a core, and viewing the "version" under "index", I'm wondering how this is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index version just tracks changes, so when you add/delete/update documents and commits happens, the version is increasing (it's doesn't mean, that change will be always an increment by 1)

This mechanism is useful in a distributed search (both [master/slave replication](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/index-replication.html#IndexReplication-SlaveReplication) and SolrCloud).

When slave checking the master index version and sees, that it's different from the version it had, than it's time to do a replication.